# Blocking all outgoing http/https requests in an iOS app to all domains except one

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, react-native

I am developing a react native app, and as a security measure in our company, to prevent potential 3rd party libraries from sending data,  we want to block **all** outgoing http traffic to all domains except our API domain on **IOS** **(cleartext or encrypted)**.

How such a goal can be accomplished?

my info.plist:

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>my.domain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

The result is that **only unencrypted traffic** (http) is blocked on all domains except my.domain, which is not the goal we are trying to accomplish. We want to block all traffic on any domain other than my.domain.

What's the best strategy to achieve this result in iOS?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "3rd party library" that is sending data that you want to block?

Comment: we are using many libraries. The requirement of our security team is to block all traffic which may come from any current or future libs we are using.

Comment: Hmmm... with that requirement of your "security team" it's very surprising that they don't also state **"No 3rd-party libraries!!!"**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS intercept all network traffic from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125565/ios-intercept-all-network-traffic-from-my-app)

Comment: yeah, the app contains sensitive information, so they are a bit paranoid :)